# Pass HTMLDocument from Sub to Function

Tags: html, vba, object, internet-explorer, parameter-passing

I am trying to reference an HMTL Document, used in a Sub, to a Function; I keep getting the following error:

> Run-time error '424':
>
> Object Required

I am fairly new to VBA, and I know I'm doing something wrong, but I just don't know what. Here is my code:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Function findAssetNumber(name1 As String, name2 As String, HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument)
    
    With HTMLDoc
        
        If Not .getElementsByName(name1)(0) Is Nothing Then
            .getElementsByName(name1)(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value
            .getElementsByClassName("panelButton")(2).Click
            .getElementsByClassName("rightAlign")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        Else
            .getElementsByName("name2")(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value
            .getElementsByClassName("panelButton")(2).Click
            .getElementsByClassName("rightAlign")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        End If
            
    End With
        
End Function

Sub Ticket()
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim locationOptions As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim terminalCount As Integer
    Dim termNumberShort As String
    Dim termNumberLong As String
        
    Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HHACRMA")
    Set locationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Location")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
        
    'Get terminal numbers
        
    termNumberLong = mainSheet.Range("B3").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("A40") = termNumberLong
    termNumberShort = Left(Range("A40").Value, 3)
        
    'Navigate to ticket system
    With ie
        .Visible = 1
        .navigate "link"
    
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
        
    End With
        
    'Adding the note/assets
        
    With HTMLDoc
         
        findAssetNumber "7.25.0.0.0.0.2.9.0.0.1.2.3.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1", _
                        "7.25.0.0.0.0.2.7.0.0.1.4.3.1.5.3.3.0.1.3.1.5.0.0.1.2.9.3.1.9.2.1.3.1.0.1.1.1.30.1.30.1.4.1", _
                        HTMLDoc
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to pass the Internet Explorer object from the Sub to the Function to make my code look cleaner. I am trying to avoid multiple If/Else statements in my Sub, so I thought creating a function that would automatically handle the if/else would be a lot easier AND cleaner. The error points to this line:

```
.getElementsByName("name2")(0).Value = mainSheet.Range("E19").Value
```

Comment: I would have expected a compile error as you don't have ByVal MainSheet As Worksheet in the function signature. Please include the relevant html as well.

Comment: I can see that you had declared the IE object globally. Instead of passing the HTML document as an argument, did you directly try to use ie.document in the function? If not, you can make a test with it. It may help you to access the document. Also, try to check whether the `mainSheet` object is available or not. Let us know about your test results.

Answer (score 0):

add ByVal before the HTMLDoc inside the function arglist

```
Function findAssetNumber(name1 As String, name2 As String, ByVal HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument)
```